# $this->Session->setFlash() display an error in cakephp 2.3.7

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks, cakephp-2.3

I'm new to cakephp and i'm trying to use $this->Session->setFlash() in my code and it says  that there is an error: Call to a member function setFlash() on a non-object! Here's my code

```
function add(){
    if(!empty($this->data)){
        if($this->Post->save($this->data)){               
            $this->Session->setFlash('The post was successfully added');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('The post was not saved, please try again');
        }
    }
}
```

What can i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check in app/Controller/AppController.php  you have 'Session' element in `$components` field.

```
  var $components =  array('Session');
```

Answer (score 2):

At first you have to add this in your controller code:

```
     var $components= array('Session');
```

It will work definitely.